# PRESTASHOP - Override behaviour on module installation

Tags: module, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am developping my own module (presta 1.5) and have been overriding some core Classes/controllers for my needs. I am enquired to install this module on an existing website.
Table creation goes according to plan, but when it comes to "installing" overrides, it crashes, stating that one of the functions I override for the ProductController has already been overridden (by a module previously installed on the said website).

So here is my question : how can I make my module automatically install (when pressing the "Install" button in the backend) for my overrides not to make it crash? Note that I entend to keep all modules previously active activated.

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

A method can be overridden only once. So if you have already installed another module which overrides the same method you cannot install your own module properly.
The only way to fix it would be to manually merge the existing override with the one of your module, remove your override from your module and then try to install your module again.

Comment: that's what I did, but I'd liek to know how to make it crash-proof upon installation so as that module can go anywhere without the user having to debug things.